# Angular - Show error message only at particular index - within ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat for a `<ul>`. However I can't see any simple way to show an error message at a particular index. I don't want it to be at every instance:

For example, in in my HTML i have:

```
<ul ng-click="apiMethod()" ng-repeat=“item in workArray”>
    <li >{{item}}
    <div>{{errorMessage}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And in my controller there is

```
$scope.apiMethod = function(){
    //An $http api call that returns the variable result
    $scope.errorMessage = result.data.message;
}
```

I know there is `$index` of my ng-repeat which I could pass into my ng-click method, but then how do i do something like:

```
$scope.apiMethod = function(index){
        $scope.errorMessage.index = result.data.message;
}
```

Hope this is clear - am new to Angular.

Thanks.

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle? my intuition is in the <div> you could do an ng-if to check if there is an error message Edit: nvm :)

Comment: Thanks - that was the correct way to go about it - using `ng-if` the answer below solved it perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do have `errorMessage` property on each element of `workArray` collection, so that they can defer individually. When calling `apiMethod` do pass reference of `item` which is current `workArray` item, then inside that method do an ajax and bind error message to same item reference `item.errorMessage`.

**Markup**

```
<ul ng-click="apiMethod(item)" ng-repeat="item in workArray”>
    <li >{{item}}
    <div ng-if="item.errorMessage">{{item.errorMessage}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.apiMethod = function(item){
    //An $http api call that returns the variable result
    item.errorMessage = result.data.message;
}
```

Comment: Awesome that works. So for my knowledge going forward if `item` doesn't have a property i can always add it - like done with `errorMessage`?

Comment: exactly, that's how objects work in javascript. however, it's good practice to initialize any properties you plan to set in a variable declaration somewhere.